# Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated

Tags: solidity

I have read a similar answer to this question. But, I don't understand why events without the `'emit'` keyword are not working now. It was working a few days ago. Now, all my contracts are breaking! Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Presumably, you recently started using a newer compiler version.

Comment: Ok, so it is due to a compiler update?

Comment: Yes. `emit` didn't  exist in old versions of Solidity. Then it was added, and then it was made mandatory.